# Bazel - Including all headers from a directory when importing a static library

Tags: c++, windows, bazel

I am a total newbie to Bazel and trying to add a static library to my build.

Lets say as a simple example say I have the following.

```
cc_import(
  name = "my_test_lib"
  static_library = "lib\my_test_lib\test.lib"
  hdrs = ["lib\my_test_lib\include\headerA.h", 
          "lib\my_test_lib\include\headerB.h"]
  visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)
```

Now this works fine.

However, what if I have a huge number of includes and within the include directory there is a number of subdirectories. Do I have to individually enter each one that my main project depends on, or can I do something like the following to essentially make all headers in this directory / subdirectories available?

```
 hdrs = [ "lib\my_test_lib\include\*"]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need is the `glob` function.

To use it in your above example, you would do something like this

```
cc_import(
  name = "my_test_lib"
  static_library = "lib/my_test_lib/test.lib"
  hdrs = glob(["lib/my_test_lib/include/*.h"])
  visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)
```

which would find all files ending with `.h` under `lib\my_test_lib\include` and put them in the `hdrs` attribute of your `cc_import`.

There's more information about `glob` in the Bazel documentation: https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/be/functions.html#glob

*Note: Always use forward slashes on all platforms in Bazel BUILD files (even on Windows).*

**Multiple glob patterns**

It's sometimes useful to put in more than one pattern in the glob, for example like this

```
cc_import(
  ...
  hdrs = glob([
    "lib/my_test_lib/include/*.h",
    "lib/my_test_lib/include/*.hpp",
    "lib/my_test_lib/public/*.h",
  ]),
  ...
)
```

**Combining a glob with a hard coded list of files**

Another useful thing is combining globs with hard coded paths. You might have a few files you want in there and then a directory you also want to include. You can do this by using the `+` operator to concatenate the hard coded list of paths with the glob results like this

```
cc_import(
  ...
  hdrs = [
    "lib/my_test_lib/some_header.h",
  ] + glob([
    "lib/my_test_lib/include/*.h",
  ]),
  ...
)
```

**Globbing a directory hierarchy (beware of massive inclusions)**

The `glob` function also support traversing directories and their sub directories when finding files. This can be done using the `**` glob pattern. So, to for example grab all `.h` files in the `my_test_lib` directory, use this glob

```
cc_import(
  ...
  hdrs = glob([
    "lib/my_test_lib/**/*.h",
  ]),
  ...
)
```

*Beware: This will include all files below the specified directory, as expected. This can go out of hand since it's not explicit what files get included. Might be better to stay away from `**`.*

Comment: Thank you for your detailed response. That explains a lot.

Answer (score 7):

[This is a supplement to [Sebastian's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56805572/751579).]
Here's a trick I just learned (from a colleague) to use with `cc_import`:

Suppose you don't want your headers exposed "naked", but want them all in a subdir prefixed by your library name, so that you refer to them like this:

```
#include <openjpeg/openjpeg.h>
```

The first step is to have a directory structure that looks like this:

```
. <library root>
- include
  - openjpeg
    - openjpeg.h
    - <other header files>
```

But now if you expose these header files via a `glob`, e.g.,
`glob(["mylib/include/openjpeg/*.h"])`
or some variant like
`glob(["mylib/include/**/*.h"])`
(or even by naming them explicitly!) they're not actually exposed as
`#include <openjpeg/openjpeg.h>`
but instead as
`#include "openjpeg.h"`
or
`#include <include/openjpeg/openjpeg.h>`
or something like that.

The problem is that `cc_import` unaccountably does *not* support the `includes` attribute that `cc_library` does so you can't just name an include *directory*.

So, use the standard computer science workaround of *adding another level of indirection* and use this:

```
cc_library(name = "openjpeg", 
           includes = ["include"],
           deps = ["openjpeg-internal"],
           visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)
cc_import(name = "openjpeg-internal",
          hdrs = glob(["include/**/*.h"]),
          static_library = ...,
          visibility = ["//visibility:private"],
)
```